# Github insight not been updated

Tags: git, github, commit

i have a repo where 2 friend of mine and I are working together, and I would like to get Insights about every contributor, however Github has stopped to count mine commits for some reason.

I've already read about [the criteria used to "approve" commits that will be counted on the insights tab](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile), and I can see from [here](http://contribution-checker.herokuapp.com/) that my problem is the following:

> Have you added the email used to author the commit (some_username_that_is_not_an_email) to your GitHub account?

However `some_username_that_is_not_an_email` is not an email, and so I cant go to my profile and add that as approved email

So I was wondering, are there other "Insight repo/website/project" that counts contributions also of not approved commits, or are there ways to get Github accepts those commits (preferably without having to change the information of each commit)?

Comment: Are you interested at general tools to show git statistics (agnostic of github) or do you want a specific tool that integrates with Github specifically?

Comment: @mnestorov i would like to see for every contributor, the number of addition and deletion (like in the insight page), but not only for the "approved" contributors, but also for the "not approved"... the repo is the following https://github.com/AlbertoSinigaglia/GestionaleQt/ adn as you can see from here https://github.com/AlbertoSinigaglia/GestionaleQt/pulse/monthly there are 4 contributors, but on the contributors tab, i can see only three of those https://github.com/AlbertoSinigaglia/GestionaleQt/graphs/contributors since one is not "approved" by the Github system

Comment: I don't know of any plugin that directly connects/works with Github and its UI, but I know a tool that you can run locally and share the results with your contributors. You can check out [gitstats](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats), which is a great tool for getting in-depth repository statistics.

Comment: @mnestorov thank you so much, 2 hours ago i've also founded it and that does exactly what i want

Comment: I'm glad it helps! Maybe you can answer your question so that others can see what worked for you :)

Comment: @mnestorov oh well feel free to give you an answer, will be more than glad to give you the votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, there isn't any (or at least any popular) project/app/plugin that can easily give out statistics and integrate at the same time with GitHub.

But there are plenty of very nice tools and apps that can give us a wide range of git-related statistics, which we can later publish and share.

I suggest using [gitstats](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats).

To use it:

```sh
# clone
git clone https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats.git
cd gitstats

# run
./gitstats <repo location> <stats output>

# view stats from output dir
firefox index.html
```

This can provide us with multiple pages of all kinds of people who have commited. Both *Github verified* and **any other** users that have validly created a commit will be mentioned in the statistical output.

This does satisfy the requirements with the only downside that it is not integrated with Github, but at least the output can easily be shared and published.